# How to recover Windows 8.1 (System) Files?

Tags: windows-8, ssd, thinkpad

I have a fairly new (purchased 8/2013) Lenovo ThinkPad T431s with Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. It has a very tricky error coming basically 8 / 10 boots: **Windows is Scanning and repairing drive**...

**Error details from Windows Event Viewer:**

> A corruption was discovered in the file system structure on volume \?\Volume{f62db2cf-efe4-4b55-a3f7-0e7db991a984}.
>
> A file on the volume is no longer reachable from its parent directory.  The parent file reference number is 0x2000000000002.  The name of the parent directory is "".  The parent index attribute is ":$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".  The file reference number of the file that needs to be reconnected is 0x400000003db80.  There may be additional files on the volume that also need to be reconnected to this parent directory.

**What is wrong (my personal analysis):**

To me, it seems that for some reason there is one (all the Event Viewer details point to similar error) corrupted / missing Windows (System) file that is causing this, but I have NO idea what the file(s) is/are.

Other symptoms on my laptop is that after logging in and using whatever app (Windows delivered or 3rd party), the whole laptop jams totally for say 30-240 seconds and all apps go to "Not Responding" state until laptop recovers **and** I can continue using my laptop "normally".

**What has been done trying to fix that:**

1. SSD disk has been changed (image from previous SSD copied back) -> *no solution, error remains*
2. `chkdsk /F /R` -> *no solution, error remains*
3. `SFC /scannow` -> *no solution, error remains*
4. `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` -> *no solution, error remains after a few boots*
5. TRIED using "Update & Recovery -> Refresh Your PC without affecting your files" -> Inserted the Lenovo "Operating System Recovery Disk Windows 8 Pro (OEM Activation 3.0 Required)" BUT Windows did not accept that DVD claiming "The media inserted is not valid"... ???
6. Ended up calling Lenovo Support and they instructed me to order the Recovery DVD from http://www.lenovorecovery.com -> Waiting that to arrive...

So anyone had this kind of problem and how to solve this (prior proper (?) the Recovery DVD arrives)? I would absolutely NOT want to re-install everything from scratch...

Comment: Try using `sfc` to replace possibly corrupted Windows files.  Aside form that, based on what you are describing, I'd suspect the drive; but you say you already replaced it, so run Memtest86+ for 48 hours and test the crap out of your RAM.

Comment: The memtest has also been done... It's quite clearly a Windows (System) file that needs to be re-installed... (see the Event Viewer details).

Comment: You can also use DISM with an online/external source image. If this keeps happening, and the SSD firmware is current, I would replace the SSD while its under warranty.

Comment: Yes, tried also `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` -> seems no final solution, error returns after a few boots...

Comment: I have just confirmed the order of `Windows 8` recovery DVD, according to Lenovo Support, it **should** also work with `Windows 8.1`.

Comment: Now this is getting interesting... I put the latest Volume ID
`\\?\Volume{f62db2cf-efe4-4b55-a3f7-0e7db991a984}` from the Event Viewer error-log to the Windows run-box and executed it.

It returned a `bootsqm.dat` -file which is NOT located in my local drive (in C: root) nor I can not find it anywhere else.Did some research and it seems that it's only created by chdsk for checking errors, but if (?) that's a temp (?) file, how come Windows tries to "fix" it almost on every boot?